# How append value in multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to add some value here:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [cat_id] => 1
            [lot_id] => 1
            [brand] => Dell
            [model] => D630
            [unit_aed] => 800
            [sold] => 0
            ** i want to append value here like this
            [username] => name

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [cat_id] => 0
            [lot_id] => 0
            [brand] => dell
            [model] => e6400
            [unit_aed] => 0
            [sold] => 0
        )


)
```

How this possible? I'm trying with `array_push($array, 'username')`.

It works fine with simple array but not work with `stdClass` Object array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another object key and value:

```
$array[0]->username = 'name';
```

Or you can add `username` to every value in that object:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val){
    $array[$key]->username = 'user';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array_name[0]->username = "name";
$array_name[0]->new_value = "whatever";
$array_name[0]->another_new_value = "whatever again";
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
$myclass = new stdClass();
$myclass->id = 4;
$array[] = $myclass;
```